# Back to figures

Tags: discussion

Sorry to drag the discussion back to figures...

I think that many questions and answers would be assisted by the inclusion of an appropriate figure or two. A rendering of the latex or a screen capture from a different program or whatever. However, in the rush to provide a fast answer, I think that people often skip the several steps required (write a file, compile it, view it, screen grab, save relevant part to disk, upload with the excellent no-so-new button), due to the time/effort it takes, or because they are unfamiliar or uncomfortable with part of the process (heck, I myself sometime can't be bothered).

I think that it is a problem and I would like to solicit feed back on two questions:

**What do you think? is it a problem? Should we somehow promote the inclusion of figures in answer and questions?**

if you think that the answer is yes, perhaps you can also answer the second question:

**How can we do it?**

I have some ideas, but I will first open the floor to others.

Answer (score 4):

I didn't know that you can easily upload figures just like that. I though you'd have to upload a figure somewhere else and then use HTML code to refer to it.

[image]

So I guess the first thing to do is to advertise that this feature *exists* and is easy to use!

Comment: Me either! And to think I'd done this the hard way a couple of times on SO...

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps we could have an easy button suggesting (with a vote perhaps?) that this question/answer would greatly benifit having a figure (or more) uploaded. This would then appear on the user's page and they would be informed of the public opinion next time they visit....

Or perhaps, we could advertise with a banner or with a popup box that uploading images is now super-easy, and link to a FAQ entry about it....

Thoughts?